# How to upload 'octet-stream' CryptoJS-AES encrypted PDF using 'form-data'?

Tags: javascript, encryption, multipartform-data, filereader, cryptojs

I found [this article](https://tutorialzine.com/2013/11/javascript-file-encrypter) from 2013 which uses FileReader and CryptoJS to encrypt and decrypt files.

I am having problems to upload the encrypted file using content-type: form-data.

How would I go about converting the encrypted output into a file that I can upload using axios and content-type: form-data?

```
import aes from 'crypto-js/aes'

const reader = new FileReader()

async encryptFile (file) {
  let fileEncrypted = null
  reader.onload = async (e) => {
    fileEncrypted = await aes.encrypt(e.target.result, 'testpw')
  }

  await reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  return fileEncrypted
}
```

Above function returns the following object:

[image]

Thank you,
MJ